# Looking for ways to schedule a python package to run

Tags: python-3.x

I am fairly new to python. Having created a working package to import google analytics report into a SQL table, I am now trying to schedule the update to execute daily. The `main()` function does the job

```py
def main():
    analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()
    response = get_report(analytics)
    print_response(response)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want the `main()` to fire up every morning at **4 AM**

Tried to add to the same package:

```py
job_to_schedule = main

def schedule_with_delay(self):
    for task in self.tasks:
        schedule.every(1).day.at("04:00").do(self.task, job_to_schedule)
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```

But running `schedule.get_jobs()` displays nothing.

Please assist. Thanks

Comment: `job_to_schedule=main()` will immediately _call_ the `main` function, and `job_to_schedule` will refer to whatever this function _returned_. Did you mean `job_to_schedule=main`?

Comment: Thanks ForceBru. Changed main() to main, still getting schedule.get_jobs()
Out[22]: []

Comment: Is `self.tasks` empty?

Comment: for task in self.tasks:
            print(task) prints empty

Comment: Well, there's the problem: `self.tasks` is empty, so no tasks are scheduled

Comment: Finally got the schedule to work. Eliminating the loop did the trick schedule.every(1).hour.do(main)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the schedule to work. Eliminating the loop did the trick

```
schedule.every(1).hour.do(main)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Thanks for your assistance